# Insert a blank date value in URL hacking?

Tags: apex, urlhacking, parameters

In URL hacking, how do you insert a blank string value for a date? We have a button that we're implementing that is like the clone button, with a couple of changes. It breaks when I try to clear out the date field. By breaks, I mean it looks like the record tries to save, and then fails because there are pagelayout security issues

I tried the following values for opp9:

%00 (null)

%20 (space)

`+` (space)

`/{!Opportunity.Id}/e?clone=1&00N30000008Qqoc=This+Opportunity+was+Cloned&opp7=0.00&opp9=&retURL=%2F{!Opportunity.Id}}`

Any ideas?

Ref: http://www.w3schools.com/charsets/ref_html_ascii.asp

Comment: Do you mean that you're trying to save an Opportunity record with a blank Close Date? What kind of pagelayout security issues are you getting?

Comment: No, I'm not trying to save it at all. I'm trying to clear out the close date when i clone the opportunity, and have it open in edit mode, so the user has to fill in a new one.  The page layout security issues I'm getting are Error: Invalid data and I'm being told that I must enter in a value. It looks almost like the record tried to save.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried actually leaving it blank?  I tried this in my dev org and it worked (it brought up the page with the CloseDate cleared out).

```
/{!Opportunity.Id}/e?clone=1&opp7=0.00&opp9=&retURL=%2F{!Opportunity.Id}
```

Notice I use `opp9=` and leave it completely blank and move on to the next parameter.

Comment: did you get the error message at the top of the page? "Error: Invalid Data. Review all error messages below to correct your data." I still get that.

Comment: That is because close date is a required field

Comment: so, it's what @caspNZ is saying?

Answer (score 1):

The `sObject.clone()` method that gets called when you invoke that URL attempts to perform a clone on the original `sObject`. It then saves that object and renders the page for you.

Unfortunately, this means you are probably going to have to roll your own clone page if you want to clear out the date from the Opportunity.

A good starting point would be [this](http://christopheralunlewis.blogspot.co.nz/2011/05/how-to-dynamically-clone-salesforce.html) blog, where the Author clones all the fields via `objectType.getDescribe().fields.getMap().keySet()`. From there you could remove the date field from the list of fields to copy. You'd then present the page to the user with the empty date field and allow the user to save from here (presenting the appropriate error messages for null date of course).

Answer (score 0):

I'm not 100% on this, but I believe using just plain null will work. Like so:

/{!Opportunity.Id}/e?clone=1&00N30000008Qqoc=This+Opportunity+was+Cloned&opp7=0.00&opp9=null&retURL=%2F{!Opportunity.Id}}

Comment: That doesn't work for date fields. you actually get the string null in the date field.